# Magento 2 : Set Catalog price rules based on customer IDs

Tags: magento2, customer, catalog-price-rules, block-cache, pricing

I need to setup a catalog price rules based on customer ID. for that i added "customer_id column in "catalogrule_product_price" table. and put condition of customer ID in getRulePrice function.
Although it works correctly but when i logout from one customer and login with another customer it still shows me discounted price from cache.
When i clear/disable the **Blocks HTML Output** cache it works perfectly.

Is there any possible solution except the cache disable? Please help!

Below is my code changes.

vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/ResourceModel/Rule.php

```
public function getRulePrices(\DateTimeInterface $date, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productIds, $cId = null)
{
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $select = $connection->select()
        ->from($this->getTable('catalogrule_product_price'), ['product_id', 'rule_price'])
        ->where('rule_date = ?', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('website_id = ?', $websiteId)
        ->where('customer_group_id = ?', $customerGroupId)
        ->where('product_id IN(?)', $productIds)
        ->where('customer_id = ?', $cId);

    return $connection->fetchPairs($select);
}
```

vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Pricing/Price/CatalogRulePrice.php

```
public function getValue()
{
    if (null === $this->value) {
        if ($this->product->hasData(self::PRICE_CODE)) {
            $this->value = (float)$this->product->getData(self::PRICE_CODE) ?: false;
        } else {

            $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $customerSession = $om->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory::class)->create();

            $this->value = $this->ruleResource->getRulePrice(
                $this->dateTime->scopeDate($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()),
                $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId(),
                $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId(),
                $this->product->getId(),
                $this->customerSession->getCustomerId()
            );
            $this->value = $this->value ? (float)$this->value : false;
        }
        if ($this->value) {
            $this->value = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndRound($this->value);
        }
    }

    return $this->value;
}
```

i just want it to work without disabling/cleanig the cache. else is working correctly.
Any suggestions?

Comment: May be a little overkill but the first think that comes to my mind would be to force the cache flush when the user login.

That being said you have this issue cause you connect with multiple users for testing purpose i guess. This should not happened in a real case scenario as people should not connect multiple accounts i guess...the only use case i see would be a family with multiple account connecting with the same device, not really something that will happen a lot i think ?

Comment: @Claims in my case i get this issue in different devices & browser i mean it shows discounted or non-discounted price from server cache. means whoever the last user loggedin in site his relevant price will show to all the user until the cache flushed.